# Does a blind creature with tremorsense still have a 50% miss chance?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

A creature with the extraordinary ability [tremorsense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Tremorsense-Ex-)

> can automatically **pinpoint** the location of anything that is in contact with the ground.

Does *pinpoint* here mean an otherwise blind creature with tremorsense can *locate a creature with perfect accuracy*, or does *pinpoint* here mean an otherwise blind creature with tremorsense can *know an appropriate creature's space but suffers a 50% miss chance*, as when locating a creature that's [invisible](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes, they still have 50% miss chance.

The creature can find the location of any invisible creature in contact with the ground automatically, as long as it is within the listed range of the *Tremorsense*.

There was a rules clarification printed in *Ultimate Intrigue* for *Tremorsense*.

> Imprecise senses allow a creature to pinpoint the location of another creature, but they don’t allow for the use of targeted effects, and attacks against those creatures are subject to miss chances from concealment. A few examples of imprecise senses are hearing, Scent, Blindsense, and Tremorsense.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you would still have the 50% miss chance. Tremorsense allows you to feel someone's location, but you're not aware of their stance or how they'll avoid your blows without your own sight. That's what total concealment represents in this case, so treat any targets as if they're invisible but their location is known.

Comment: This is correct, also see the distinction between blindsense and blindsight in that same list of universal monster rules for a bit more unpacking of the concept.

Comment: @mxyzplk My question stems from precisely that. While [blindsense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Blindsense-Ex-) delivers a raft of explanatory text, [tremorsense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Tremorsense-Ex-) contains none, so I thought it could be a case of the designers simply lacking synonyms. Can support for this answer's position besides *That's how I read it* be marshaled?

Comment: Parallel statements + common sense suffice for most.

Comment: @mxyzplk Nothing about blindsense and tremorsense is parallel except both end in *sense* and their descriptions contain the word *pinpoint.* And can you pinpoint for me where in *Pathfinder* I can find the entry for *common sense*? `:-)`

Comment: What about [total concealment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Concealment)?